# ld: framework not found Flutter

Tags: flutter

И при запуске через `flutter run`, и через `vsCode` выходит ошибка

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
    invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly
    because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select
    a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

Comment: Приложите лог из `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте **Flutter** в **PATH**: `export PATH=$PATH:/.../flutter/bin`

Answer (score 0):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale ru-KZ)
• Flutter version 1.22.1 at /Users/madibikamalov/MobileDeveloper/flutter
• Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (5 days ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
• Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
• Dart version 2.10.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
✗ CocoaPods not installed.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
sudo gem install cocoapods

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
for detailed instructions).

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1.2)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
• For information about installing plugins, see
https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins